How can I prevent image from re-rendering multiple times in the webpage in Next.js project
I am working on a project using Next.js. while I created a banners page and uploaded one image to it, it was rendering multiple images at once both in the web page and the console. I've tried so many ways to solve the problem but still can get it to render the exact image.
Now further, while I populated it with two more banner images with react-slick to give me the carousel effect, upon adding banner-Text, the result was not good. it was showing all the banner-text for each banner on just one banner while the rest of the banner is not displaying its banner-text. Please can someone help me on how I can get over this strange behavior or suggest what I can do to get the exact effect of my code.
This is the code I tried to implement:
Link to the code in codesandbox (both banner and bannerText component)
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/stoic-clarke-qdhdt2
Link to the outlook of the text distortion on bannerImage:
The Outlook of the ERROR of the bannerText on one of the banner image in a slider. All the text meant for each banner is jampacked and showing just on this image. What could be causing this a no error is thrown in my console or terminal making it difficult for me to debug.

Hi Akin, can you create a codepen with your issue for easy understanding?

You can share code blocks by using codepen or codesandbox. Difficult to understand the problem in this current way.

@praizjosh... Thanks for your kind attempt in trying to help out. However, i have edited it with a sample codesandbox just to provide a clearer view of the code snippet for better assessment. i will be grateful if i can find the possible cause of the re-rendering and also why text is not showing properly on the banner image as well. Thanks.

@Anwar Hossain... Thanks for your kind attempt to trying to help me out of this frustrating scenario. However, i have provided a codesandbox to just show the code snippet of both the banner and bannerText component for clearer view and assessment on what could be causing this issue.  Thanks...

@Akin it appears the codesandbox is accessible to the public. Can you pls change the workspace permission to public?

@praizjosh, Thanks again. I think I have altered the change.
